# Server.MapPath with query string in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, uri, server.mappath

After some 15 mins of Goooooogling, I cannot find a solution to this simple problem. So some little help?

The application is hosted in a `web` subfolder of the website, I need to map a relative Uri (which is a `Hello` action in the `RouteController` which takes an int and a string as parameters):

```
"~/Route/Hello/129?name=kennyzx"
```

to

```
http://myserver/web/myapplication/Route/Hello/129?name=kennyzx
```

If I use

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Route/Hello/129?name=kennyzx");
```

It throws an exception because the question mark `?` is an illegal character.

So I need to first separate the Uri into two parts `~/Route/Hello/129` and `?name=kennyzx`, then `MapPath` takes the first part, and `Path.Combine` concatenate the result of `MapPath` and the query string.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

**I realize I am using the wrong API, it actually expands to the real file path on my server!**

This is what I am trying to do:

I have a bunch of relative uris and I want to write a function to expand them to absolute uris, in Razor page.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Route Testing";
    var link1 = "/Route/Hello/129?name=kennyzx";
    var link2 = "~/Route/Hello/129?name=kennyzx";
}

@functions{
    private static string GetAbsoluteUri(string link)
    { 
        string absoluteUri = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(link);
        return absoluteUri;
    }
}

<h2>Route Testing</h2>

<a href="@link1">@link1</a><br />
<a href="@link2">@link2</a><br />
<a href="@GetAbsoluteUri(@link2)">@link2</a><br />
```

But none of the above get the correct absolute path.

The first expands to http://myserver/Route/Hello/129?name=kennyzx,

The second expands to http://myserver/web/myapplication/~/Route/Hello/129?name=kennyzx

The third throws an exception and that is why I am asking this question.

Comment: Why do you want to append the querystring onto a folder name?   That's pointless

Comment: this is not a folder name, it is a Hello Action in RouteController which takes an int (id) and a string as parameters.

Comment: Okay, `Server.MapPath()` returns a folder.  I think you need to rethink your question and clarify what you want to do.  For example, `Server.MapPath("~/index.html")` may return `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.html`

Comment: @Archer Thanks. I have edited my question. Now I understand it is not the right API. Basically I just want to access that link from a Razor page, the difficulty is the application is not deployed to the root of the website but in a virtual directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Server.MapPath` returns the actual path on the server like `file:///C:/somefolder/somefile`. It is not used to resolve relative urls.

Turns out what I am looking for is [@Url.Content](https://webactivedirectory.com/asp-net/asp-net-use-url-content-from-razor-to-resolve-relative-urls/) to resolve relative urls in Razor page.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Route Testing";
    var link1 = "~/Route/Hello/129?name=kennyzx";
}

<h2>Route Testing</h2>

<a href="@Url.Content(@link1)">@link1</a><br />
```